# Google Searchbar in Python Selenium element not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

service=Service(r"D:\chrome_driver\chromedriver_win32(1)\chromedriver.exe")
op=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s=webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=op)
s.get("https://www.google.pl/")
search=s.find_element(By.NAME,"q")
```

And got

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The old tutorials and answers does not work

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get rid of Accept/Reject cookies window, which is actually intercepting your action.

Try the below code:

```
s.get("https://www.google.pl/")
# below line will click on "Accept all" button
s.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']").click()
search=s.find_element(By.NAME,"q")
```